# How to get URL values to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

How to get parameter value to javascript variable?
As an example:

`<a href="page.php?id=10&value='hello'">click me</a>`

Here, I want to get the key named `id`, and its value `hello` to assign them to a javascript variable. How to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) class.

```
const url_params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = url_params.get('id');
console.log(id);
```

Comment: Not so simple. The value in question is `"page.php?id=10&value='hello'"`, which is an invalid URL search param input. You'll either need some reliable way to get rid of `page.php`, or build the full URL and use the built-in `URL` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let name of document.querySelectorAll("a")) {  
var Reg = /page.php\?id=(\d+)\&value=%27(.*?)%27/g;  
var Array;
while ((Array = Reg.exec(name.href)) != null){
console.log(Array[1]);
console.log(Array[2]);
}  
}
```

regex